# Remove characters from string (String normalization?)

Tags: excel, vba, string, normalization

I am attempting to remove characters from a string in excel by utilizing a VBA macro.For example the string is "UOZV3A-WB1○1.8ml vbn958Xzlv2" and I need it to return "UOZV3A-WB1". It is pretty straight forward, the code I am using is:

```
For Each c In Range("D2:D69")
If InStr(c.Value, "?") > 0 Then
    c.Value = Left(c.Value, InStr(c.Value, "?") - 1)
End If

Next c
```

The issue I am running into is a single character in the string ("o") is unrecognized by the macro. The string is entered into the cell by scanning a QR code. I suspect that "o" is a sort of placeholder that is recognized/interpreted as a "o" in excel but interpreted differently in VBA. If I try to just copy and paste the character into VBA I get a "?".

Is there a way to manipulate or interpret that character in VBA? Some of the other posts I read seemed to indicate that the string could be normalized but the coding was over my head.

Thanks!

Comment: The character is the 11th in your string.  If that string is in A1 then the formula `=CODE(MID($A$1,11,1))` will tell you the Ascii code for the character.  In VBA use `Asc(Mid(Range("A1"), 11, 1))`.  Once you know the Ascii number you can use `If Instr(c.Value, CHR(63))>0 Then` (replacing 63 with the correct number).

Comment: Thank you very much. I hadn't thought about the characters in terms of Ascii codes. I was able to get it to work that way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand what character you are parsing on:

```
Sub junkkiller()
    For Each c In Range("D2:D69")
        If InStr(c.Value, ChrW(9675)) > 0 Then
            c.Value = Left(c.Value, InStr(c.Value, ChrW(9675)) - 1)
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the clarification. I hadn't thought about determining the code for that character.

Comment: @ThomasBever  Glad to help.  Thanks for the feedback!